# Native JavaScript Float32Array faster than asm.js with SIMD?

Tags: matrix, three.js, simd, emscripten, asm.js

I wanted to speed up multiplyMatrices function from three.js by creating an asm.js module. When I finally managed to get it running it looks like it's slower than native JavaScript using Float32Array operations

my asm.js is using code from http://fhtr.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/4x4-float-matrix-multiplication-using.html:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>

#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
int main()
{
}
struct vec4
{
    __m128 xmm;

    vec4(__m128 v) : xmm(v) {}

    vec4(float v) { xmm = _mm_set1_ps(v); }

    vec4(float x, float y, float z, float w)
    {
        xmm = _mm_set_ps(w, z, y, x);
    }

    vec4(const float *v) { xmm = _mm_load_ps(v); }

    vec4 operator* (const vec4 &v) const
    {
        return vec4(_mm_mul_ps(xmm, v.xmm));
    }

    vec4 operator+ (const vec4 &v) const
    {
        return vec4(_mm_add_ps(xmm, v.xmm));
    }

    vec4 operator- (const vec4 &v) const
    {
        return vec4(_mm_sub_ps(xmm, v.xmm));
    }

    vec4 operator/ (const vec4 &v) const
    {
        return vec4(_mm_div_ps(xmm, v.xmm));
    }

    void operator*= (const vec4 &v)
    {
        xmm = _mm_mul_ps(xmm, v.xmm);
    }

    void operator+= (const vec4 &v)
    {
        xmm = _mm_add_ps(xmm, v.xmm);
    }

    void operator-= (const vec4 &v)
    {
        xmm = _mm_sub_ps(xmm, v.xmm);
    }

    void operator/= (const vec4 &v)
    {
        xmm = _mm_div_ps(xmm, v.xmm);
    }

    void operator>> (float *v)
    {
        _mm_store_ps(v, xmm);
    }

};

int mmul_vec4 (float *a, float *b, float *r)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i += 4) {
        vec4 rl = vec4(a) * vec4(b[i]);
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
            rl += vec4(&a[j * 4]) * vec4(b[i + j]);
        }
        rl >> &r[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

Code in JavaScript which runs this asm.js module(malloc moved to init because the function is being reused 500/sec), also most pointers are calculated manually to reduce amount of code. Anyway this is still ~2x slower than the Float32Array native JavaScript version.

```
Maths.prototype.init = function () {
    // Alloc memory we need (16 fields x 4 bytes each + 8 additional for each field) * 3 = 216

    this.dataPtr = Module._malloc(216);
    // Import function from Emscripten generated file
    this.mmul_vec4 = Module.cwrap(
      'mmul_vec4', 'number', ['number', 'number', 'number']
    );
};
Maths.prototype.matrix4multiply = function(matrix1, matrix2, target, callback) {
            App3d.Maths.prototype.matrix4multiplyBlocking = function(data, data2, dataTarget) {
    // Copy data to Emscripten heap
    new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, this.dataPtr, 64).set( new Uint8Array(data.buffer, data.byteOffset, 64) );

    // second matrix allocate and copy to emscripten's heap
    new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, this.dataPtr + 72, 64).set( new Uint8Array(data2.buffer, data2.byteOffset, 64) );

    // multiply first two parameters and return in the last one 
    this.mmul_vec4(this.dataPtr, this.dataPtr + 72, this.dataPtr + 144);

    dataTarget.set(new Float32Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, this.dataPtr + 144, 16));
};
```

Original Three.js function

```
multiplyMatrices: function ( a, b ) {

    var ae = a.elements;
    var be = b.elements;
    var te = this.elements;

    var a11 = ae[ 0 ], a12 = ae[ 4 ], a13 = ae[ 8 ], a14 = ae[ 12 ];
    var a21 = ae[ 1 ], a22 = ae[ 5 ], a23 = ae[ 9 ], a24 = ae[ 13 ];
    var a31 = ae[ 2 ], a32 = ae[ 6 ], a33 = ae[ 10 ], a34 = ae[ 14 ];
    var a41 = ae[ 3 ], a42 = ae[ 7 ], a43 = ae[ 11 ], a44 = ae[ 15 ];

    var b11 = be[ 0 ], b12 = be[ 4 ], b13 = be[ 8 ], b14 = be[ 12 ];
    var b21 = be[ 1 ], b22 = be[ 5 ], b23 = be[ 9 ], b24 = be[ 13 ];
    var b31 = be[ 2 ], b32 = be[ 6 ], b33 = be[ 10 ], b34 = be[ 14 ];
    var b41 = be[ 3 ], b42 = be[ 7 ], b43 = be[ 11 ], b44 = be[ 15 ];

    te[ 0 ] = a11 * b11 + a12 * b21 + a13 * b31 + a14 * b41;
    te[ 4 ] = a11 * b12 + a12 * b22 + a13 * b32 + a14 * b42;
    te[ 8 ] = a11 * b13 + a12 * b23 + a13 * b33 + a14 * b43;
    te[ 12 ] = a11 * b14 + a12 * b24 + a13 * b34 + a14 * b44;

    te[ 1 ] = a21 * b11 + a22 * b21 + a23 * b31 + a24 * b41;
    te[ 5 ] = a21 * b12 + a22 * b22 + a23 * b32 + a24 * b42;
    te[ 9 ] = a21 * b13 + a22 * b23 + a23 * b33 + a24 * b43;
    te[ 13 ] = a21 * b14 + a22 * b24 + a23 * b34 + a24 * b44;

    te[ 2 ] = a31 * b11 + a32 * b21 + a33 * b31 + a34 * b41;
    te[ 6 ] = a31 * b12 + a32 * b22 + a33 * b32 + a34 * b42;
    te[ 10 ] = a31 * b13 + a32 * b23 + a33 * b33 + a34 * b43;
    te[ 14 ] = a31 * b14 + a32 * b24 + a33 * b34 + a34 * b44;

    te[ 3 ] = a41 * b11 + a42 * b21 + a43 * b31 + a44 * b41;
    te[ 7 ] = a41 * b12 + a42 * b22 + a43 * b32 + a44 * b42;
    te[ 11 ] = a41 * b13 + a42 * b23 + a43 * b33 + a44 * b43;
    te[ 15 ] = a41 * b14 + a42 * b24 + a43 * b34 + a44 * b44;

    return this;

},
```

Comment: Which browser are you using, and which version? These are new features which aren't particularly well optimized by all browsers.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm using the latest build of Chromium (don't know if SIMD in Emscripten is working). Also using latest Firefox beta where SIMD is working. In Chrome is definitely slower, in Firefox I'm trying to get it running again.

Comment: Chromium currently doesn't support SIMD.js, but Bill is working on it: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/2PIOEJG_aYY

Comment: @JFBastien I'm looking forward to it! Is there a way to turn any in-progress version on using a flag or something? I remember there was a build a while ago where it could be enabled using "--js-flags=--simd-object" flag, but it was some kind of custom Intel's build I think and doesn't work with official Chromium builds. It was different than current Firefox's implementation i.e. SIMD.Float32x4 was called SIMD.float32x4: http://peterjensen.github.io/idf2014-simd/